# Is this a Salafi site?

Tags: discussion

Is this site controlled by Salafis? As I see many  question answers from Salafi perspective.

thanks

Comment: Who are salafis?

Comment: Who r Salafis and what is wrong with them?

Comment: I thought it was controlled by the shi'ites

Answer (score 5):

Not exclusively.  We as a site are controlled by the community at large, which is open to all schools and denominations of Islam. Even when there is heavy Salafi traffic, questions explicitly seeking answers from non-Salafi viewpoints are entirely welcome here.

Comment: The Question here is why the questions were given as Salafi Perspective, Either we should mention that it is from salafi Perspective or answer should be given which will be applied to all the schools.

Comment: @ali786 Again, the site is open to Salafi and non-Salafi posts alike, but it's up to the community to keep that under control; if you think it's an issue that warrants discussion, feel free to open a new meta topic on it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Salafi (nor am I Muslim), but I sometimes ask questions about the Salafi perspective of Islam because of actions taken by Salafi Muslims that are reported in the media. For example, [Is taking hostages permitted in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21664/is-taking-hostages-permitted-in-islam)